# Count # unique values of column if all values in corresponding values are identical

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique

[image]

I'm looking to have E2 and E3 count the number of unique entries in column B based upon met criteria in column A.

**Complete** (E2) would count all of unique entry *Address1* in column B **only** if *any status* of *Address1* is set to *Cancelled* **or** *Installed*. **Pending** (E3) would count all of unique entry *Address2* and unique entry *Address 3* only if **all** *corresponding status'* are *Pending*.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?  What formula have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

With Office 365 we can use nested Filters and Match to return the list of items that meet the necessary criteria those with and without anything but `Pending`.  Then we use UNIQUE to make the list unique and COUNTA to count the number of returns:

For Completed:

```
=LET(itm,B2:B10,sts,A2:A10,unq,(UNIQUE(FILTER(itm,ISNUMBER(MATCH(itm,FILTER(itm,sts<>"Pending"),0))))),IF(ISERROR(@unq),0,COUNTA(unq)))
```

For Pending:

```
=LET(itm,B2:B10,sts,A2:A10,unq,(UNIQUE(FILTER(itm,ISERROR(MATCH(itm,FILTER(itm,sts<>"Pending"),0))))),IF(ISERROR(@unq),0,COUNTA(unq)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Formula I used in `E2`

```
 =SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$10,($A$2:$A$10="Cancelled")+($A$2:$A$10="Installed")))<>""))
```

In `E3` formula is

```
=SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$10,($A$2:$A$10="Pending")))<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: The second one will not suffice `Pending (E3) would count all of unique entry Address2 and unique entry Address 3 only if all corresponding status' are Pending.`  with enphasis on the `all`.  If you change A6 to `Cancelled` it is supposed to count as Complete not Pending.  and it will count as both with your formula.

Comment: You are correct. I didn’t think that. Will try to accomplish that. Thanks for pointing.